# How to make nav element 100% width (so other elements will be under it, not right after it)

Tags: html, css

Sorry for my not very good english.

To understand my problem look [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uuyp8/4/) and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uuyp8/5/).

Take a look on the `<nav></nav>` part. If there are not many elements in menu, next block `<section></section>` will be right after menu. If there are many elements in menu all fine, because `nav` has enought width.

How to make next :

[image: site]

And nav must be 100% width not depending on amount of elements.

html `<body>` code:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <center>
                <!-- logo and headers here -->
            </center>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <!-- menu here -->
        </nav>
        <section>
            <header><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1></header>
             <!-- main content here -->
        </section>
        <aside>
            <section>
                <header>
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <!-- block content here -->
                </header>
            </section>
        </aside>

        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

css code:

```
body {
    color: #8f8f8f;
    background-color: #f8f8f8; 
    background: url(../images/background.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat #f8f8f8;
    /* border: 5px solid #7e7e7e;*/
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #7e7e7e;
}

header {
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: auto;
}

aside, section {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

section {
    float: left;
    width: 700px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
}

aside {
    float: right;
    width: 240px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

aside section
{
    width: 230px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

section header {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0px;
}

section header h1 {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

section p {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/* css for nav */
```

Comment: You should post relevant css and html here too not just a link to fiddle

Comment: oops. sad. my code broke js fiddle :D 1 moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nav is appearing on the left because you haven't cleared your floating lis.  If you add the following style then it should work:

```
nav:after {clear:both; display:block; content:'';}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/Uuyp8/6/)

Answer (score 4):

I make it a point of always adding a `.clearfix` css class to my reset stylesheet, as you will most likely need to clear out floated regions more than once in your site. It helps to give containers with only floated content back their height.

Add this to your stylesheet

CSS

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix{
    *zoom:1;
}
```

Then add `class="clearfix"` to your `<nav>` element (or even on your `<ul class="nav">`)

Here is a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uuyp8/8/

This `clearfix` solution is based upon the (famous?) micro clearfix hack explained in more detail here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Pete answer is same and it will be accepted. He was first :( Thank you . It works.

Comment: class vs style. i would argue slightly different :P but i do see he was first for the solution at hand :)

Comment: Yes, you have class, he has element. A bit different. But both methods are same, nope? So I accepted his method. Btw, I used your :) More beautiful I think :)

Answer (score 2):

Make `nav` `float:left` and the pink section `clear:left` (Or nav `clear:right`, same effect).

Comment: Section already has `float: left;`, so I can't use your method. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes, but does it have "clear", like I suggested? That is the trick (same as in accepted answer)